# Search and compare images in folder

Tags: image, search, compare, directory, imacros

How can I search and compare images in my folders with iMacros?

iMacros should compare an image on the website with the pictures in my folder on the desktop. Then, do a checking so when it matches the image in the folder, do something. Else, if it doesn't match anything, do something else.

Comment: I tried to clarify the problem. However, I don't know anything about iMacros, so feel free to rollback or improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with iMacros and it CAN'T be done.

The only way to do it with (free version) is to use a php combined with iMacros. Using local server you can combine the php script to compare images and result to be outputted on localhost.